# Mean of the product of a Gaussian random variable and a function of the same variable

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

I've been asked to prove that if $X$ is a Gaussian random variable with zero mean and $F$ a function then:

$$\langle XF(X)\rangle = \langle X^2 \rangle \langle F'(X) \rangle $$

Where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the mean.

I see clearly that it must be some sort of consequence of integrating by parts but I haven't been able to prove it yet. I also don't get why I get the product of two integrals in the RHS instead of a single integral.

Comment: Hint: write the mean as integral and apply integration by parts

Comment: The use of $F$ to denote the CDF has become so common that its use here to denote an arbitrary function can cause a double take on the part of the reader.

Comment: @user251257 Yes, I am trying to do that, but I don't see how to get rid of the minus sign when I do it and I don't see how I get two integrals instead of just one (of $-X^2F'(X)/2$).

Comment: Make sure you are treating $\langle X^2 \rangle$ as a constant - that might cause confusion if the $X^2$ term is coming up in your integrals.

Comment: @A.A. $\langle X^2 \rangle = \sigma^2 = var(X)$. That factor should appeals naturally after integration by parts. The fact that $X$ is Gaussian and has 0 mean is crucial.

Comment: Btw you might need some growth conditions on $F$, like it's bounded or  $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} x^2 F(x)e^{-x^2} = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\langle XF(X)\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x F(x) \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,dx=-\sigma^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, F(x)\,\, de^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}=$$ 
$$=-\sigma^2 \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} F(x)\,e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\biggm|_{-\infty}^\infty + \,\sigma^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \,e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} dF(x)=$$
$$=\sigma^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \,e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}F'(x) \,dx = \langle X^2 \rangle \langle F'(X)\rangle.
$$

One need here that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}F(x)e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}=0$.